# Hide the slide using the add notes in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, zoom

In PowerPoint I used to hide some content of the slide by dragging the add notes. Now I have another PowerPoint file and I can't do the same thing: every time I try to drag the add notes it changes the zoom of the slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to:

- delete the elements of the slide instead
- changing the zoom yourself after resizing the notes aread
- put a rectangle shape with the color of the background to cover the elements you want to hid